# How can I put an infoWindow at the top of a custom marker?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, marker

Here is my code demo: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/manhhailua/ue1cqe22/)

I created a custom marker to use instead of google marker. Then I want to show a infoWindow contains the address of the marked position. But the infoWindow always points at the same position with the custom marker. I want it to be at the top of the custom marker (like [this demo](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/infowindow-simple?hl=vi)).
Thanks for reading!

HTML:

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&region=uk&language=en&sensor=true"></script>
<div id="map_canvas" style="height: 350px;width: 500px;margin: 0.6em;"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.customMarker {
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #9acfea;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-left: -50px;
    margin-top: -110px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 0;
}

.customMarker:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -10px;
    left: 40px;
    border-width: 10px 10px 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #9acfea transparent;
    display: block;
    width: 0;
}

.friendsCustomMarker {
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #f57977;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-left: -50px;
    margin-top: -110px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 0;
}

.friendsCustomMarker:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -10px;
    left: 40px;
    border-width: 10px 10px 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #f57977 transparent;
    display: block;
    width: 0;
}

.customMarker img, .friendsCustomMarker img {
    width: 90px;
    height: 90px;
    margin: 5px;
    border-radius: 10px
}
```

JS:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to:

1. set the pixelOffset appropriately
2. set the position of the infowindow

[working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ue1cqe22/1/)

working code snippet:

```js
// Custom marker
function CustomMarker(latlng, map, imageSrc) {
  this.latlng_ = latlng;
  this.imageSrc = imageSrc;
  // Once the LatLng and text are set, add the overlay to the map.  This will
  // trigger a call to panes_changed which should in turn call draw.
  this.setMap(map);
}

CustomMarker.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();

CustomMarker.prototype.draw = function() {
  // Check if the div has been created.
  var div = this.div_;
  if (!div) {
    // Create a overlay text DIV
    div = this.div_ = document.createElement('div');
    // Create the DIV representing our CustomMarker
    div.className = "customMarker";


    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = this.imageSrc;
    div.appendChild(img);
    /*google.maps.event.addDomListener(div, "click", function (event) {
     google.maps.event.trigger(me, "click");
     });*/

    // Then add the overlay to the DOM
    var panes = this.getPanes();
    panes.overlayImage.appendChild(div);
  }

  // Position the overlay
  var point = this.getProjection().fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.latlng_);
  if (point) {
    div.style.left = point.x + 'px';
    div.style.top = point.y + 'px';
  }
};

CustomMarker.prototype.remove = function() {
  // Check if the overlay was on the map and needs to be removed.
  if (this.div_) {
    this.div_.parentNode.removeChild(this.div_);
    this.div_ = null;
  }
};

CustomMarker.prototype.getPosition = function() {
  return this.latlng_;
};
$(function() {
  var lat = 44.88623409320778,
    lng = -87.86480712897173,
    latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);

  var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      panControl: true,
      panControlOptions: {
        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT
      },
      zoomControl: true,
      zoomControlOptions: {
        style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE,
        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_left
      }
    },
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);
  marker = new CustomMarker(latlng, map, 'http://d33vud085sp3wg.cloudfront.net/hnmsBpTlK58BG3iOK3G4Cd5Iqlw/thumb.jpg');
  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  infoWindow.setContent('Here is an info window!');
  infoWindow.setPosition(latlng);
  infoWindow.setOptions({
    pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(0, -110)
  });
  infoWindow.open(map);
});
```

```css
.customMarker {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #9acfea;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-left: -50px;
  margin-top: -110px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 0;
}
.customMarker:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -10px;
  left: 40px;
  border-width: 10px 10px 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #9acfea transparent;
  display: block;
  width: 0;
}
.friendsCustomMarker {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #f57977;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-left: -50px;
  margin-top: -110px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 0;
}
.friendsCustomMarker:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -10px;
  left: 40px;
  border-width: 10px 10px 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #f57977 transparent;
  display: block;
  width: 0;
}
.customMarker img,
.friendsCustomMarker img {
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  margin: 5px;
  border-radius: 10px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&region=uk&language=en&sensor=true"></script>
<div id="map_canvas" style="height: 350px;width: 500px;margin: 0.6em;"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use pixelOffset property:

```
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({pixelOffset:new google.maps.Size(0, -100)});
```